# Slider Revolution + BarbaJS (PJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, pjax, revolution-slider

I'm trying to get Slider Revolution sliders to reinitialize within BarbaJS.

I'm currently setting up functions originally notated by ThemePunch's documentation:

```
// RevSlider
function getCurrentSliderAPI() {
    var slider = jQuery('.rev_slider');
    if(!slider.length) return false;
    return eval('revapi' + slider.attr('id').split('rev_slider_')[1].split('_')[0]);
}
// Start RevSlider
function startSlider() {
    var revapi = getCurrentSliderAPI();
    if(revapi) {
        revapi.revstart();
        console.log('Slider ' + revapi + ' started.');
    }
}
// Kill RevSlider
function killSlider() {
    var revapi = getCurrentSliderAPI();
    if(revapi) {
        revapi.revkill();
        console.log('Slider ' + revapi + ' killed.');
        revapi = null;
    }   
}
```

The getCurrentSliderAPI function seems to have issues. I set console logs in order to make sure that function is actually working in the other two functions, to no avail.

With this current set up, I have this console error: `revapi1 is not defined` upon loading into the page from another with the slider activated.

Any help in getting the Revolution Slider to initialize on page transitions would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: After a year of trying to get this to work, I've discovered that this was technically answered three years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25191095/4220832

This looks to be the answer to the issue I need, even though it's about the jQuery version. I would have to place the slider inside of an iframe in order to get it to reinitialize, since it removes the iframe and reloads it in a new one. This isn't ideal to use iframes, but it reduces the memory leak issue as well.

Comment: How exactly did you slove the issue? Can you provide some sample code? html as well as js? Would be greatly appreciated!